# Data not showing in grid table, even though it's there

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angular

I have a controller method

```
        [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public IActionResult Makes()
    {
        var data = _vehicleService.GetMake(0, 10);

        return Ok(data);
    }
```

It works, I debugged it and data is filled with the data required. The problem comes when you need to use it in angular and create a view.
I have just started using angular, and from what I see; it's a bit harder to debug.

In my component I have this typescript file

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
selector: 'app-fetch-data',
templateUrl: './fetch-data.component.html'
})
export class FetchDataComponent {
public makes: Makes[];

constructor(http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
http.get<Makes[]>(baseUrl + 'api/SampleData/Makes').subscribe(result => {
  this.makes = result;
}, error => console.error(error));
}

}

interface Makes {
Id: number;
Name: string;
Abrv: string;
}
```

And this is the view

```
<h1>Makes</h1>

<p *ngIf="!makes"><em>Loading...</em></p>

<table class='table' *ngIf="makes">
<thead>
  <tr>
  <th>Id</th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Abrv</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr *ngFor="let make of makes">
  <td>{{ make.Id }}</td>
  <td>{{ make.Name }}</td>
  <td>{{ make.Abrv }}</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

So since the data is filled with the data needed, I assume the typescript constructor does it's job and calls the method, but the data doesn't show in the grid table, it's empty.
Does it matter that an interface created in the same class, which I assume gets the info. Can I use my viewmodel instead of that interface somehow?

Comment: what's your console.log(result) returns, try to print it

Comment: @ganesh045 it prints an array of the items that it gets from the database. So it is filled with data. https://i.imgur.com/q05rzwi.png

Comment: I would recommend you make the http calls on ngOnInit rather than the constructor of your component

Comment: Could you give an example? Also wouldn't the same problem occur? I can do that after I get the basics to work.

Comment: In your component have a method like this: ngOnInit(): void { } and in this method do what you're currently doing in your constructor. You'll need to store the params you're passing in. It's not recommended to have complex code in the constructor - see https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

The problem was the HTML code. I used make.Id, but when console.log(result) I noticed the id is lowercase. Changed it to make.id and works.